# Migration of data from one DB to another DB

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

Both my databases are on the same server, `DB1`contains new and old data, `DB2` contains old data.`DB1` contains different tables and columns then the ones that are in `DB2`. What I am worried about is overwriting old data and creating duplicates. Both have different primary/foreign keys and relationships
I have a query,

```
update t1
set description = t2.description
from db1.dbo.foo t1
  join db2.dbo.foo t2
  on t1.itemid = t2.itemid
```

What I would like to do is check if the record exists already and if all values match to not create a duplicate. If some values do not match update the record with the most recent one. Could I do this by using a unique ID?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that db1 and db2 itemid are identical?

Comment: @Chandru, actually I cant be sure

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do utilize the Exists Key word.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT DB1.<column_where_data_is_being_checked> 
           FROM DB1.dbo.table_name DB1 INNER JOIN DB2.dbo.table_Name 
           DB2 ON DB1.<unique_ID> = DB2.<unique_ID> 
           WHERE DB2.<column_where_data_is_being_checked> =
                 SELECT DB1.<column_where_data_is_being_checked>
                 FROM DB1.dbo.table_name DB1)
UPDATE...
```

This should work you may have to modify the query inside the exists statement and build a different staging table that you can drop after the update. If the value doesn't exist it will just keep on going through the list. This website has more information about this concept https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx